# How to build a Non Blocking Asynchronous Web service Using Spring boot

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-boot, nonblocking

I have a RestFul Webservice that i have designed using Spring Boot.

The web service is quite heavy as it has to make a lot of Database calls while starting up and also some to the rest ends make heavy IO operations to serve up results.

I want to make the Restful Api as Asynchronous so that it can be more scalable and also it dosent take time to serve up it's results.

I looked in Spring async https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

I even implemented this but i am not able to test if this is async .

Like what if i want something like

if a request is made to url /all

it shows like web service is processing result instantly and then after all the process is done it shows the actual result .

How is this possible ?

Also i looked into this http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/04/22/c10k-developing-non-blocking-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/.

There is no code in this question as this is a design issue i am facing as how to fix it please bear with me . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot automatically supports [Servlet spec 3+ async handling of http](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html) requests.

The simplest way to leverage that is like so:

```
public Callable<ResponseEntity<?>> myProcessingMethod () {
    return () -> ResponseEntity.ok (myHeavyService.doTheWork ());
}
```

The point of the above is to release your HTTP request handling thread as quickly as possible, so that it is ready for the next request.
Once your service call has completed, control will return to the http handling thread, so that the result can be sent to the caller.

Now, if you would instead like to have a service method execute async, you can annotate that method with `@Async`. 
BUT, you can then NOT use that method in a rest handler like above.

The above code will need to change to something like:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> myProcessingMethod () {
    myHeavyService.doTheWorkAsync ()
    return ResponseEntity.ok ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two separate questions there.

1. How do I build async server in Java
2. How do I test its performace

In my opinion, your solution to the first one is valid. Of course you can use [Vertx from within SpringBoot](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples), or [Quazar](http://www.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/), or [Akka](http://akka.io). But it depends on your use cases.

To your second question, I would suggest using [wrk tool](https://github.com/wg/wrk). Since your code shouldn't block so much, you'll be able to process much more concurrent requests. You should only note that it's best to run `wrk` from a separate machine, and not from the server where your Java runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public interface Callback<T>{

public void callWhenDone(T result);
//process the result in you implemenation
}
```

Start a Thread for Processing DB Queries

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
   Callback callback;

     //create thread by passing implemenation of callback
     public MyThread(Object parameter,Callback c) {
            // store parameter for later user 
            this.callback=c;    


     }
     public void run() {
       //call db queries and when  you get the results call the callbak
       callback.callWhenDone(result);
   }
}
```

Start the thread new MyThread(params,CallBackImplemntation).start()